# Handling async array with javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am trying to do is upload multiple files with this code and create array location filled up with location.
But when i try to console.log location after the for loop, it returns empty result.
Can any one help me with this problem? Uploading S3 worked very well. Just failed to make an array 'location'.
Try to solve this problem for 4hours in a row...
I would appreciate your help.

```
var arr = []
const uploadToS3 = async() =>{
var i = 0;
for (i;i<images.length;i++){
  var file =  
  {
    name: brandInput.value+"-"+productNameInput.value+"-"+i+".jpg",
    type: "image/jpeg",
    uri: images[i].uri
  }
  RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => arr.push(response.body.postResponse.location));
}
```

}

Comment: 1) You're not initializing `i` to `0` and 2) You're performing asynchronous logic within a synchronous loop.  The loop will terminate before the asynchronous logic finishes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I have changed my full code I'll take a look at your links Thanks a lot. God Bless You Guys

Comment: can you guys take a look at my code again? i try to under stand async await with codesandbox and other examples but i got stuck again

Comment: First make `uploadToS3` to be async function. Then move the return statement to be in front of this `RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => {` so it should become `return RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => {` and remove the `return arr` code and it should work.